# Consequences of a missing init?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, init, nsobject

In the process of porting a really badly coded iOS project to OS X, in which I make a point of preserving the model layer in order to (later) being able to keep the two versions in sync.

I do not currently have access to change the iOS code base - and don't particularly want to, either. Also, for all its faults, the model layer is tested and working.

If it ain't broke don't fix it, they say. So I guess my question is, *is* the code below broke or not? Notice there is no call to `init` after the `alloc`, and the class being instantiated is a direct subclass of `NSObject`.

```
...
SuspectClass *obj = [SuspectClass alloc];
obj.arrayProperty = [NSArray arrayWith...];

// etc.
...
```

I guess another way to put the question is if `NSObject`'s `init` actually adds anything to an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of `init` in NSObject comes the official answer: "An object isn’t ready to be used until it has been initialized."

...and the practical answer: "The init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self."

:-)

Though functional, I don't think I'd trust a bare `alloc` given the number of places that warn that some form of `init` is required.

Comment: +1 The code works now because NSObject's init **currently** does nothing and because its own init **currently** does nothing and it **currently** inherits directly from NSObject.  There's three things that could change in the future that will break the code, one of which only Apple can control.

Comment: I am aware that things may change in the future - I guess that my desire to keep the codebase shared between the two projects overrides my desire to do things as they should be done, if that for the current version of the code will not actually change anything. Thanks for the answers - and I guess I should have read the docs better!

Comment: @Monolo: Keep in mind that it's not like Apple is going to send you an email the day they change `init` to do something in the next version. You'll find out about the change when users upgrade to the newest OS, your app breaks, and the users start leaving 1-star reviews.

Answer (score 0):

without init you get an "object" (at least enough space in memory for the 'object') in an undefined state. You cannot know what happens to that place in your memory, so init is a must